# How do I set up calendar sharing in Salesforce?

Tags: sharing, event, calendar

Currently, our organization utilizes Calendar Sharing in the My Personal Information section in Salesforce.

We have a team that makes calls that manages calendars for the Account Executive team. Currently as a Salesforce admin I log in as each Account Executive, and add each user of the phone team as something the Account Executive shares their calendar with.

Is there a better way to do this, utilizing org-wide defaults and sharing rules?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up moving the phone team (SDRs) above the Account Executive Team in the role hierarchy.

This also opened up some access we wanted for opportunity and event deletion.